# Better to use a database, or have individual php files for each showcase?

Tags: php, html, database

So I have almost finished my website, however the only thing left is to make an individual showcase (this includes pictures and information) about each object. However, I am wondering if I should use a database to do this, or have each individual file for each showcase that corresponds to the object. Currently I have 16 objects, and will add about 4-5 per 6 months, so with so many objects, that is why I was thinking maybe a database is the best idea? Or if there is another way, instead of have 20 php files.

So what I would like is the user to view my gallery.php page and when they click on a certain object it brings them to a page with information and pictures.

You can view my current page at http://darthvixcustomsabers.com/gallery.php

[enter link description here](http://darthvixcustomsabers.com/gallery.php)

Also here is my code for the gallery.php

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>

    <P id="service">Gallery of Completed Lightsabers</P>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <section class="column">
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/corran.jpg">
        <p>GCS: Corran Horn</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/kraytsaber.jpg">
        <p>Krayt Dragon Saber   </p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/sk.jpg">
        <p>JK Starkiller</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/firstascend.jpg">
        <p>GCS: Custom Ascend</p>

    </div>

</section>

<section class="column">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="images/quigon.jpg">
        <p>Qui-Gon Jinn</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/adi.jpg">
        <p>One Replica Adi Gallia</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/kiadi.jpg">
        <p>One Replica Ki-adi Mundi</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/jacen.jpg">
        <p>Jacen Solo</p>

    </div>

</section>

    <section class="column">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="images/kitfisto.jpg">
        <p>Kit Fisto</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/kotor.jpg">
        <p>Kotor(Revan) Lightsaber</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/lukev2.jpg">
        <p>LDM Luke V2</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/lukehero.jpg">
        <p>JQ Luke Hero</p>

    </div>

</section>

    <section class="column">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="images/mando.jpg">
        <p>Custom Mandalorian Lightsaber w/ Crystal Chamber</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/mara.jpg">
        <p>JK Mara Jade</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/darkascend.jpg">
        <p>Custom Dark Ascend</p>

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/lukehero.jpg">
        <p>JQ Luke Hero</p>

    </div>

</section>
                 <?php include 'footer.php';?>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I do have some experience with databases and retreiving database information, but if there is a better way, or even if an individual file for each object is the best, I am open to anything.

Thank you

Comment: Database will be the best option though

Comment: If its static html your are displaying you go go for something like wordpress or textpattern?

Comment: Yea database is what I thought best, however I want like Pictures(glams) and then specs for the object, and them a little blurb. So I would need a column for each picture, so if I want each to have 4 pictures, have 4 columns, and then have 1 column as specs, and 1 as blurb?

Comment: @Terry Yeah, you would need 4 columns if 4 separate images, Also I suggest maybe creating a separate page for the specifications, passing through the items ID to display the information. As i'm guessing you are aware you will need to have an ID column in your database, being auto incremented, just so each item can be uniquely identified.

Comment: @Alex, I am not sure if this is against the rules, but could I possibly hire/pay you to set it up and teach me how you did it? or if you cannot is there somewhere I can get someone to? I know databases would be super useful, not only for this project, so it would be nice to get good at them

Comment: @Terry I'm not sure if it is or not, But I'd be happy to help you out without that, I could help you out a little bit on here to help you get started? Do you currently have a database of any kind?

Comment: Yea I am using phpmyadmin through go daddy, I named the database and table sabers and it has 6 columns

Comment: Ah okay, seems like your on the right tracks, I'm not sure how I can offer you much help on here, but if you need any specific help with anything, let me know? and I'll see what I can do, I wish they had a private inbox chat system on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a database is by far the best choice if you have the knowledge, It will allow you to far more quickly and easily update the objects you are show casing,

Entering them manually on a php file will just result in more work later on when you wish to change them, or even update them.